# Runbook execution New-AzSqlDatabaseImport error "dont not have authorization to perform action"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-runbook

Access control set for Automation Account [IAM]

- SQL DB Contributor Resource group (Inherited)
- SQL DB Contributor Subscription (Inherited)
- Storage Blob Data Contributor Subscription (Inherited)

Running under a system-assigned managed identity.

Need to execute Runbook to restore DB from the bacpac file backup in Azure Blob storage, but getting the error below:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable
> "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The client
> 'GUID' with object id 'GUID' does not have authorization to perform
> action 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/import/action' over scope
> '/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/dev/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/app-sql'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

Please advise what permissions I may be still missing?

Answer (score 0):

I created automation account in azure and go to run book click on browse gallery.
Image for reference:

[image]

In browse gallery searched for backup azure sql database to blob and imported it.
Image for reference:

[image]

Published that runbook and click on edit and go to test pane and filled require details.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I run it but I got below error.

[image]

In my case I entered incorrect storage account name that's why I got this error. After correcting that it run successfully.
Along with that once check all the details are correct and the networking settings of storage account and SQL server.
storage account Networking:

[image]

[image]

bacpac file is exported successfully to the blob storage.
Image for reference:

[image]

Blob storage;

[image]

We are having another way to export bacpac file into blob storage ad sql database level.
By clicking export option, we can do this.
Image for reference:

[image]

select the storage account where we want to store.
Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Are you running your Automation account as "Running under a system-assigned managed identity"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/migrate-run-as-accounts-managed-identity?tabs=sa-managed-identity 
Because out of box the script you referred to (and I used) gives an error: Connection AzureRunAsConnection not found.